# Can I communicate between two local html files using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I have two local .html files in the same folder. One page opens a window with the other page, and attempts to call a function in the newly opened window. However, the function call fails, and I get this in the console:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///***/A.html from frame with URL file:///***/B.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

This happens on both Chrome and Webkit (Mac). Is there any way I can either: disable the cross-domain checks for the file:// protocol, or call a javascript function in a different local file?

Comment: Can you run a small static webserver instead? This is trivial thing in Go or Node.js.

Comment: I could, but I really wanted to just be able to double-click the .html files. I'm currently using a VirtualHost on my main server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window.postMessage to do something like this:

The initial window html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var otherWindow;
            function openOther() {
                otherWindow = window.open("other.html", "otherWindow");

            }

            function otherFunc() {
                otherWindow.postMessage("otherFunc", "*");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div onclick="openOther()">Open the other window</div>
        <div onclick="otherFunc()">Call the other window's function</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Html for the second window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                alert("The other window's function executed.");
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is the other window.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a good reference for [window.postMessage](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Comment: It should also be noted that there are good reasons for the protections in place for cross-domain calls.  This solution is disabling the origin check by passing "*" as the second argument in window.postMessage() but you really should utilize this mechanism with some kind of check within your listener function.

Comment: I'd totally forgotten about postMessage! This was very helpful.

Comment: Awesome, glad it was useful.

Comment: Is it possible to send the selected file in one html / window to another window ? I tried couple of way, but IE is breaking my nerves

Comment: There's no way I know of to directly send a file, but you could convert it to text and send via PostMessage(), save to local storage which is accessible between windows, or use a server to relay the file data directly if these aren't feasible.  There are several other mechanisms I can think of that you could also utilize.  I've found that there's almost always a way of achieving your goal, even when the technology doesn't cooperate.  Good luck!