# How i can control elements from another html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I have tags for buttons in buttons.html and images in images.html.
When i turn on button from buttons.html i want to hide 1 image from images.html.
How i can do this?
This is buttons from buttons.html

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"> <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span> <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span> </label>
  <img src="image.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#myonoffswitch ~ img
{
    display:none;
}
#myonoffswitch:checked ~ img
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: how are you loading multiple html files on a single page? are they being imported? iframed?

Comment: you might want to check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545883/can-i-communicate-between-two-local-html-files-using-javascript

Comment: i need something like an imported source or somthing else, i don't know..

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
    #myonoffswitch ~ img
    {
     display:none;
    }
    #myonoffswitch:checked ~ img
    {
     display:block;
}
```

to

```
.myonoffswitch ~ img
    {
     display:none;
    }
    .myonoffswitch:checked ~ img
    {
     display:block;
}
```

start there for me.