# How to let 2 html pages communicate

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, communication

i'm new to web tecnologies, and i'm trying to make some stuff work. I have 2 similar html pages, with the same table on them.

I have to make sure that every data inserted in the first table (editable) is replicated in the same cell of the second table (of the other HTML page).
HTML code I used is really simple, I've added some style with CSS and 3 functions with JS (add, delete and modify row). I have to replicate these changes to rows too.

I'm a bit confused, I think I have to manage this thing with a server application, maybe in php, but i don't know how to start.

I've searched this site, but I didnt find anything useful, for now.
How can I approach this problem? I want to learn these things, I am not asking you for having working code and easily solve the problem...
Thanks to everybody in advance.

Comment: You dont need a server application. You can use some javascript libraries like Angular, knockout, etc to bind your data in both html pages.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545883/can-i-communicate-between-two-local-html-files-using-javascript

Comment: Did you have two HTML separate page or just two table in one HTML page ?
If you want your datas to be saved you will need a database to handle it.

Comment: i have 2 separate tables, in 2 separate html pages. the main problem is to get them communicating.

Comment: if they have to communicate to different clients, i.e. at different locations, you could use websockets to push your changes.

Comment: no, for now i want to run this application locally, i only wanted to get how to create this communication, maybe with a php function that could manage changes on the first html page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data somewhere (database, local storage, cookie, file, etc.), and read it when page loads.
The most common way is to store the data in database.

When your page loads, get the data from the database and build the table.
This is a good place you can start learning how to work with MySql database: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score -1):

**Angular JS** library will be a simple solution to your problem.