# Post data from html to another html

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to post data from html to another html

I know how to post data html->python and python-> html

I have dictionary in the html (I get it from python - `return render_to_response('page.html', locals()`)

how can I use with the dictionary in the second html file?

Comment: try to save your data in local storage and use them in other HTML page

Comment: you could use sessionStorage or localStorage to persist information, if pages are from the same origin.

Comment: ok, I will try it, thx

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and window.addEventListener as described in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545883/can-i-communicate-between-two-local-html-files-using-javascript) .

Answer (score 0):

If you are not gonna use any sensitive data like password you can use `localStorage` or `Url Hash` .